# What's the best caching mechanism to use for .Net web applications?

Tags: .net, asp.net, caching, memcached

What caching mechanism should I use for a .Net web application?  Memcached seems to be the best for the LAMP stack and Linux in general, but I'm not so sure that it's the answer for a .Net web application running on Windows.  My requirements are that it be distributed and that it run on Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a distributed caching system as mature as memcached for Windows, but [Velocity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/cc655792.aspx) is the distributed caching system being built by Microsoft and has a beta version available for download.

Though what I've seen a lot of people do is run memcached on Linux, and use one of the .NET clients for memcached in their ASP.net code.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [ScaleOut StateServer](http://www.scaleoutsoftware.com/products/stateServer/index.html) - it was primarily developed to provide high performance, out-of-process, distributed session management in a web farm scenario, but it is for general-purpose caching as well.

It is a mature product too - but it ain't free. The main benefit is it was designed specifically to work with the ASP.NET / Windows stack.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET offers two caching strategies out of the box, application caching and page output caching. For more information please see [ASP.NET Caching Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178597.aspx):

> Often an application can increase
>   performance by storing in memory data
>   that is accessed frequently and that
>   requires significant processing time
>   to create. For example, if your
>   application processes large amounts of
>   data using complex logic and then
>   returns the data as a report accessed
>   frequently by users, it is efficient
>   to avoid recreating the report every
>   time a user requests it. Similarly, if
>   your application includes a page that
>   processes complex data but that is
>   updated only infrequently, it is
>   inefficient for the server to recreate
>   that page on every request.
>
> To help you increase application
>   performance in these situations,
>   ASP.NET provides caching using two
>   basic caching mechanisms. The first is
>   **application caching**, which allows you
>   to cache data you generate, such as a
>   DataSet or a custom report business
>   object. The second is **page output
>   caching**, which saves the output of
>   page processing and reuses the output
>   instead of re-processing the page when
>   a user requests the page again.

Comment: Neither of those have anything to do with the type of distributed cache the OP is asking about, unfortunately.